# java - how to replace a jPanel based on user clicks

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

i have a jPanel containing 3 menus--lets call it MenuPanel
i place it on the top of my jFrame (border_layout top).
i have also 3 jPanels (PanelOne, PanelTwo, PanelThree) and i want it to be showed on the bottom of the jFrame (border_layout bottom) based on the menu that the user choose

Comment: So where's the problem? What does prevent you from replacing the panel in the bottom slot upon a menu selection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution: use a CardLayout to help you swap JPanels.

- Place a JPanel that uses CardLayout in the BorderLayout.SOUTH position, say called cardHolderPanel.
- Add the three "card" JPanels into the cardHolderPanel using unique String constants.
- Swap the cards by calling `show(cardHolderPanel, APPROPRIATE_STRING_CONSTANT)` on your CardLayout.

Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html